# Unable to make the following code work to blink my ardiuno

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Below mentioned code is what the utility I want I want my code to recognize my face and light the led while it's true.I understand I need to throw in true while the box appears it will basically feed 0/1 boolean logic to my ardiuno but I am not sure how to achieve that.

My Attempt

```
import cv2
import sys
import serial
cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags= cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Functionality I want

```
import serial
import cv

loop = True
cap = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 9600)

while loop:

    # Read image
    temp = cv.QueryFrame(cap)

    # Create another image to hold Black&White version of image
    image = cv.CreateImage((temp.width, temp.height), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)

    # Convert original image to B/W - Only because calculations are apparently better
    cv.CvtColor(temp, image, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

    # Use Haar Classifier for face detection (Magic Black Box)
    storage = cv.CreateMemStorage()
    haar=cv.Load('./haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    detected = cv.HaarDetectObjects(image, haar, storage, 1.2, 2,cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, (100,100))

    # Returns a list, the first item of which is a tuple
    # First element of tuple is x, second is y, third and fourth are width and height
    # We pass these params to create a rectangle. If we had not converted a b/w image
    # we can have a red border around instead
    if detected:
        cv.Rectangle(image, (detected[0][0][0], detected[0][0][1]), (detected[0][0][0] + detected[0][0][2], detected[0][0][1] + detected[0][0][3]), cv.RGB(255, 0, 0), 3)
        ser.write('Just a really really long string to see something')


    # Create a named window and display image in it. Key press kills window and exits
    cv.NamedWindow('Nik')
    cv.ShowImage('Nik', image)

    char = cv.WaitKey(33)
    if (char != -1):
        if (ord(char) == 27):
            loop = False
```

I managed to solve it and uploaded the code on github anyone is interested.
[Face-Detection+Ardiuno](https://github.com/Coding-Karma/Face-Detection-Ardiuno)

Comment: Communication needs two sides, you showed us only one.

Comment: @KlausD. Pardon?

Comment: I figured it out :)